# adding submenu items

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, menubar

I want to show a submenu items to the existing submenu.
Please check the http://jsfiddle.net/nw9tU/216/

In Menu2,  **Withdraw** submenu item, i want to show 2 submenu items named Savings Acc,Current Acc on mouse over on "Withdraw" sub-menu item.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Below is the sample code :

```
var pSubMenu2 = new DropDownMenu({});
var pSubMenu3 = new DropDownMenu({});

pSubMenu2.addChild(new MenuItem({
    label: "Credit"
}));
pSubMenu2.addChild(new MenuItem({
    label: "Withdraw"
}));
pSubMenu2.addChild(new PopupMenuBarItem({
    label: "Retail",
     popup: pSubMenu3
}));  

pSubMenu3.addChild(new MenuItem({
    label: "Savings Acc"
}));
```

I can able to show one submenu item on mouse over of Withdraw submenu but in the dropdown menu their is a gap seen when child menu items are added. How to resolve it and how can i show multiple submenu items to submenu. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nw9tU/215/)

basically you have to create new Menu and attach it as a popmenu item on Withdraw menu item as mentioned Below

`var withdrawMenu = new Menu({
                id: "withdrawMenu"
            });

```
withdrawMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
            id: "savings",
            label: "Savings Acc"
        }) );
withdrawMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
            id: "checking",
            label: "Checking Acc"
        }) );

var pSubMenu2 = new DropDownMenu({});
pSubMenu2.addChild(new MenuItem({
    label: "Credit"
}));

 pSubMenu2.addChild(new PopupMenuItem({
            id: "withdraw",
            label: "Withdraw",
            popup: withdrawMenu
        }) );`
```